# can not load javascript file into HTML in a flask app

Tags: flask

[this is my html file *index.html]*[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXgi7.jpg)

[this is javascript file[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5PTV.png)

[this is project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSK9K.png)

i have tried importing javascript file as:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/static/js/sc.js') }}"></script>
```

so I tried two methods for loading javascript file into html in flask app.

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/static/js/sc.js') }}"></script>
```

second one is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/sc.js"></script>
```

but i am not getting my results.
What to do Now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using following code:

```
<script src="../static/js/sc.js"></script>
```

plus also deleting the cached data of browser.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `static` from your link. You have:

```py
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/static/js/sc.js') }}"></script>
```

Instead, you should have:

```py
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/sc.js') }}"></script>
```

Also, modify your app structure to:

```py
project
  | -- app/
        | -- static/
              | -- sc.js
        | -- templates/
               | -- index.html
        | -- app.py
```

Your `app.py` file should not be in `templates/`.

Comment: i have tried it but it's not working for me

Comment: Have you tried to modify your app structure?

Comment: my app structure is correct .app.py is outside templates folder

Comment: My bad, I have edited the link to remove `static` from the filename part. Try that

Comment: already have tried that,but still not working